# What is the best way using gulp to split karma tests into runnable chunks?

Tags: javascript, gulp, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

We have an AngularJS project with about 20K LOC and 80% test coverage, so we have a lot more tests than Karma will run in one group.  We've looked at fixing the memory leaks, but between the AngularJS injector, ui-router, and closures for each describe and it spec, it feels like a problem too large to fix.

So, we have resorted to splitting out our tests into groups.  This works well until a group starts to exceed about 1,200 tests, and then it just starts slowing down until we add enough to eventually crash the browser.

I recently got rid of the manual management of splitting out the tests, and just have gulp iterate over each of the source directories and create a task with gulp.task for each one.

It works, but it kind of feels like I'm pushing against how gulp wants to work rather than letting it do the work for me.

Is there a plugin or better way to approach this?

Comment: Did you solve this in an interesting way? Even if "no," can you share your existing gulp solution?

Comment: We still have gulp run tests on each directory as a separate test run.  Our gulp files are sprawling, specific to our environment, and not a good model for anyone :).  I think, fundamentally, our problem is that we do not have good separation of Angular modules. Because of this, we end up recreating most of the services for every single test. Splititng that out, and moving from Angular services to ES2016 modules (which would just get created once) would help a lot, I think.  I think we'd also benefit from splitting out our application into modules that would not have to be part of every build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [karma-parallel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-parallel) to split up your tests across multiple browser instances. It runs specs in different browser instances and is very simple and easy to install:

```
npm i karma-parallel
```

and then add the 'parallel' to the frameworks list in karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    frameworks: ['parallel', 'jasmine']
  });
};
```

[karma-parallel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-parallel)

Disclosure: I am the author